# PHP regular expression to check string contains upper and lowercase letters

Tags: php, regex

What is the simplest regular expression that will check if a string contains at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase?

Edit: This is for a password where there may be numeric characters present as well, so the uppercase and lowercase chars might not be next to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you mean "ASCII character".

- Simple: `[A-Z].*[a-z]|[a-z].*[A-Z]`
- Elegant: `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])`

The "simple" variant just checks for the two possibilities: Either the uppercase character comes *before* the lowercase, or it's the other way around.

The "elegant" variant uses two positive look-ahead assertions to scan the string without actually moving the regex engine forward or matching anything.

In contrast to the first method, this variant is very easily extendable for more checks and it allows you to *consume* the string after you checked that it meets your requirements.

Comment: I think you can hit Unicode letters as well: `^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Ll})` Not tested though.

Comment: Sorry, original question modified slightly.  I neglected to mention there might be numericals in there as well.  Will the second solution work for that?

Comment: @BadHorsie Yes, just add another look-ahead. The first variant gets a lot more complicated since with three things to check it's no longer 2 possibilities of arrangement, but 6.

Comment: @Justin: True. It's worth noting that not all regex flavors support this natively (popular ones like JavaScript's or PHP's don't, for example)

Comment: @Tomalak - Yeah, I didn't know about PHP, that's why I wasn't sure if that would work. I only found out this week that JS regex has [almost no awareness](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode) of Unicode. [According to this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), PHP (like Ruby) will support them if you use the `u` flag. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Checking for both upper and lower case in a string can also be accomplished without a regular expression.

The code for this would look like the following:

```
$word = 'AA1FAa';

// Check if word has both uppercase and lowercase letters
if(strtolower($word) != $word && strtoupper($word) != $word){
    echo 'Has both upper and lower case letters';
}else{
    echo 'Does not have both upper and lower case letters';
}
```